# Whats the difference between form based authentication Vs Oauth 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0

I have read multiple articles but cant clearly understand . Whats the main difference between them .
i want to implement oauth 2.0 and i followed following approaach :-

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

i think the following approach is using **form based And jwt** token Both For Authentication and it is not using any refresh token and grant so its not full oauth 2.0 implementation i think ?

So it would be helpful if anybody can explain whats the diffrence between form  based authentication vs oauth 2.0 ?

i have read following question but it clearly dosen't state anything :-

> [Difference between Forms based authentication and Token based Authetication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999855/difference-between-forms-based-authentication-and-token-based-authetication)

Answer (score 0):

Forms based authentication may or may not use cookies to create a User identity, this cookie is sent with every request a user makes from browser after login, the contents of cookie is encrypted.

On the other hand OAuth 2.0 is a specification or you can say its a protocol for authorization that is widely used in industry.

Token based authentication is widely used with web Api and most common implementation of it is bearer token, a token is an encrypted string which holds different values grouped together that holds user identity and custom data if added. Token based authentication uses OAuth protocol.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api                                         can you suggest what is following link Using For Authentication Form Based  or OAuth 2.0 ?

Comment: Your refereed example uses  bearer tokens for authorization

Comment: OAuth my friend

Comment: But The Author In code is written that he is using form based authentication ! Thats why confused and cookies are used in this project to send authentication data